# Extract string meeting a condition from a url that can change

Tags: python, parsing, url, extract

I am looping through a list of weblinks and scraping an underlying url address. Sometimes the extracted url has this structure:

```
     http://www.amazon.com/dp/B07DLTSZVP?tag=snag04-20
```

and other times the extracted url will look like this:

```
      https://www.amazon.com/s?field-asin=B01NCZM14C&rh=i%3Aaps%2Cssx%3Arelevance&field-keywords=best+minimalist+wallet
```

In each case I just want the 10 digit string inside each url starting with the uppercase "B" (i.e. "B07DLTSZVP" or "B01NCZM14C").

I have included an if, elif and else statement within my loop to extract this specific string, depending on whether the extracted url looks like the first or second case above (it will only ever be these two cases), but it is not working. My code simply extracts the entire url without parsing it based on my if statements. Thanks for any help on a solution. Here's my code:

```
list = []

for index, row in filtereddf3.iterrows():

url = row[' href']
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

if soup.find('a', attrs={'id': 'view-amazon'}) is None:
    zero = 1 
elif '-asin=' in soup.find('a', attrs={'id': 'view-amazon'})['href']:     
    zero = soup.find('a', attrs={'id': 'view-amazon'})['href']
    zero[zero.find("=")+1:zero.find("&rh=")]     

else:
    zero = soup.find('a', attrs={'id': 'view-amazon'})['href']
    zero[zero.find("dp/")+3:zero.find("?tag")]


df = pd.DataFrame({'asin': zero}, index=[0])
time.sleep(3)
list.append(df)
final_list = pd.concat(list)
```

Comment: `zero[zero.find("=")+1:zero.find("&rh=")]` is just an expression. I suppose you want to assign it to `zero`? `zero = zero[zero.find("=")+1:zero.find("&rh=")]`

Comment: Oh my. Thank you for highlighting the obvious.

Comment: can you provide the url in case there are other ways?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple regular expression

```
B\w{9}
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/ZZqqMQ/1/).